# Are there any options to check if my carts were merged in Spartacus and trigger a global message?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have integrated only cart page in my marketplace app and I want to show a global message when carts were merged. How can I check if my carts were merged or not?
I do not see any [Merge] Actions to work with, mb there is something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the cart being merged from `anonymous` to a `current` user, then you would need to hook into the action `MERGE_CART_SUCCESS`, which is `[Cart]` Merge Cart Success.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `MultiCartService` and trigger your `GlobalMessage` when     `mergeToCurrentCart` is called.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import {
  GlobalMessageService,
  GlobalMessageType,
  MultiCartService,
  StateWithMultiCart,
  UserIdService,
} from '@spartacus/core'
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store'

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class YourMultiCartService extends MultiCartService {
  constructor(
    protected store: Store<StateWithMultiCart>,
    protected userIdService: UserIdService,
    private globalMessageService: GlobalMessageService
  ) {
    super(store, userIdService)
  }

  mergeToCurrentCart({
    userId,
    cartId,
    extraData,
  }: {
    userId: string
    cartId: string
    extraData?: {
      active?: boolean
    }
  }) {
    super.mergeToCurrentCart({ userId, cartId, extraData })
    this.globalMessageService.add(
      { key: 'miniLogin.mergeCart' }, // <- add your Message/key here
      GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_CONFIRMATION
    )
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add your service to the `providers` section of your app module:

```
providers: [
  ...,
  {
    provide: MultiCartService,
    useExisting: YourMultiCartService,
  },
]
```